# Django: first_name and last_name not displaying

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a page on my applicatiton where a user can see their first_name, last_name, username, and email that they provide to the application. So far, I've got the app to display the username and email, but the first_name and last_name won't display unless I manually enter them in the appropriate fields on the admin site.

Student model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Snippets of views.py:

```
def get_personal_information(request, username):
    user = Student.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'polls/personal_information.html', {"user":user})

def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"], email=request.POST["email"], first_name=request.POST["first_name"], last_name=request.POST["last_name"])
        new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
        Student.objects.create(user=new_user, first_name=str(request.POST.get("first_name")), last_name=str(request.POST.get("last_name")), email=str(request.POST.get("email")))
        new_user.is_active = True
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('../')
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

Snippets of admin.py:

```
class StudentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Student
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'student'


class Studentadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    inlines = [StudentInline]
```

Any ideas on why it's not displaying first_name and last_name?

EDIT:

```
<form method="post" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">First name:</label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="username">Last name:</label><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="confirm">Confirm Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="confirm" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Create new user account" />
</form>
```

EDIT:
In the first_name and last_name forms, I forgot to change "for=username" when I copied and pasted it over. Resolved!

Comment: Are you sure the first_name and last_name are being parsed to the DB? Do a `SELECT * FROM Table;` in the DB and confirm that the information is there. Can you also provide the .html file contents in the above? (Need to see the information you're passing to the POST parameter)

Comment: I added the HTML file.

Comment: What about the SQL results?

Comment: Why aren't you using a Django ModelForm?